# SwiftUI, navigationLink within a ForEach

Tags: swiftui

How would one, put a navigation link within an array and set that in to ForEach Loop.

I currently have tried putting the destination name as a string in the array shown at the bottom of the code then referencing that after the destination of the navigation link that i am trying to loop.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RowViewBody: View {
    
    var item: BodyTab = BodyTabItems[0]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("The Body")
                .font(.title)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack (spacing: 30){
                    //BodyParts
                    
                    ForEach (BodyTabItems) { item in
                    
                        NavigationLink(destination: item.TabLink) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Image(item.TabImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(item.TabTitleEnglish)
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text(item.TabTitleKanji)
                        }
                        .padding(.all)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 240, height: 210
                               , alignment: .bottomLeading)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .background(LinearGradient(
                         gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9349854589, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)), location: 0),
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.01684027910232544, green: 0.21824999153614044, blue: 0.40416666865348816, alpha: 0.20999999344348907)), location: 1)]),
                         startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: -0),
                         endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                    /*//Muscles
                    NavigationLink(destination: BodyMuscles()) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Image("Layer_2")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Muscles")
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("筋肉")
                        }
                        .padding(.all)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 240, height: 210
                               , alignment: .bottomLeading)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .background(LinearGradient(
                         gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 1)), location: 0),
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.01684027910232544, green: 0.21824999153614044, blue: 0.40416666865348816, alpha: 0.20999999344348907)), location: 1)]),
                         startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: -0),
                         endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    }
                    //Skeleton
                    NavigationLink(destination: BodySkeleton()) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Image("Layer_2")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(height: 100)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Skeleton")
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                            Text("骸骨")
                        }
                        .padding(.all)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 240, height: 210
                               , alignment: .bottomLeading)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .background(LinearGradient(
                         gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 1)), location: 0),
                         .init(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.01684027910232544, green: 0.21824999153614044, blue: 0.40416666865348816, alpha: 0.20999999344348907)), location: 1)]),
                         startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: -0),
                         endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)))
                        .cornerRadius(20)*/
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Vocabulary Groups")
        .padding(.leading)
        .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
}

struct RowViewBody_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RowViewBody()
    }
}


struct BodyTab: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var TabImage: String
    var TabTitleEnglish: String
    var TabTitleKanji: String
    var TabLink: String
    
}

var BodyTabItems = [
    
BodyTab(TabImage: "Layer_2", TabTitleEnglish: "BodyParts", TabTitleKanji: "体の部分", TabLink: "BodyBodyParts"),
BodyTab(TabImage: "Layer_2", TabTitleEnglish: "Muscles", TabTitleKanji: "筋肉", TabLink: "BodyMuscles")
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdn8v.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvYTT.png)

Comment: What is the question? You have shown the code you have tried but not explained why it isn’t working. 

Comment: I am receiving an error "Generic struct 'NavigationLink' requires that 'String' conform to 'View'" on the same line as the NavigationLink Line of code under the ForEach. 

I cant add an image to this comment so I will edit the post and add the Images.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to pass String instead View to destination link. The easiest way to improve this error to wrap up your string in Text that conforms to View.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.TabLink))
```

If you want to use additional data from item it's better to create separate View for that

```
struct DetailView: View {

  let item: BodyTab

    var body: some View {
      Vstack {
        Text(item.TabLink)
        Image(item. TabImage)
      }
    }
}
```

Using in NavigationLink

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item))
```